# stripe.js: api call that calls stripe.charges.create isn't returning a response

Tags: javascript, express, stripe-payments

I'm trying to use stripe.js and return the created charge after saving it on the server. The stripe charge saves successfully and is saved in my stripe test account, but it seems like the callback isn't working. From my code below, the console.log('success') gets called, but the "then" callback isn't called, and the console.log('savedChanges') doesn't get called either. Am I doing something wrong? I was following https://stripe.com/docs/tutorials/charges for reference.

**/app/scripts/controllers/stripe.js**

```
'use strict';

app.controller('StripeCtrl', function ($scope, $location, $http) {
  $scope.charge = {};
  $scope.successfulCharge = null;

  $scope.submitCharge = function(status, response){
    var $form = $('#payment-form');

    if (response.error) {
      $form.find('.payment-errors').text(response.error.message);
      $form.find('button').prop('disabled', false);
    } else {
      var token = response.id;
      var data = {
        amount: ($scope.charge.amount * 100),
        card: token,
        description: "2014 missions donation for " + $scope.charge.missionary,
        metadata: {
          'email': $scope.charge.email,
          'missionary': $scope.charge.missionary
        }
      };

      $http.post('/api/stripe/submitCharge', data).success(function(data, status, headers) {
        console.log('submitCharge success!!!');
        console.log(data);
        $scope.successfulCharge = data;
      });
    }
  }

  $scope.getCharges = function(){
    $http.get('/api/charges').success(function(charges) {
      return charges;
    });
  }
});
```

**/lib/controllers/api.js**

```
'use strict';

var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    config = require('../config/config'),
    stripe = require('stripe')(config.stripe.secret_key),
    Charge = mongoose.model('Charge');

exports.charges = function(req, res) {
  return Charge.find(function (err, charges) {
    if (!err) {
      return res.json(charges);
    } else {
      return res.send(err);
    }
  });
};

exports.publishable_key = function(req, res){
  return res.send(config.stripe.publishable_key);
};

exports.submitCharge = function(req, res){
  var savedCharge;
  var result = stripe.charges.create({
    amount: req.body.amount,
    currency: "usd",
    card: req.body.card,
    description: req.body.description
  }, function(err, charge) {
    if (err) {
      console.log('errors');
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      console.log('success');
    }
  }).then(function(charge){
    savedCharge = Charge.create({
      name: charge.card.name,
      amount: charge.amount,
      email: charge.metadata.email,
      address: charge.card.address_line1 + charge.card.address_line1,
      city: charge.card.address_city,
      state: charge.card.address_city,
      zip: charge.card.address_zip,
      tax_receipt: charge.metadata.tax_receipt,
      missionary: charge.metadata.missionary,
    });
  });

  console.log('savedCharge');
  console.log(savedCharge);
  return res.send(savedCharge);
};
```

Answer (score 4):

It looks like the [Stripe API](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node#api-overview) gives you the ability to use a callback *or* a promise, but you're using both in your call to `charges.create`:

```
var result = stripe.charges.create({
 ...data...
}, function (err, charge) { // <-- callback
 ...
}).then(function(charge) { // <-- promise
 ...
})
```

You need to choose one or the other.  That is, either put the call to `Charge.create` inside the callback from `stripe.charges.create` (where your `console.log('success')` is) or move your error handling to the promise by providing a second argument to the `then()` statement: a function with an `err` parameter.